# delete duplicate record from same table in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have one table named `tblm_customer`.

It contain field named `firstname` and `lastname`. Now I want to delete all records from the table that contain the same firstname and lastname that are already in the table.

I used mysql database and `customerid` is the primary key in the table.

Comment: Do two records with the same firstname/lastname have also the same customerid?

Comment: no customerid is unique as it is primary key

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows from a MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770228/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following delete removes all duplicates, leaving you with the latest CustomerID

A note of warning though. I don't know your use case but it is perfectly possible to have two people with the exact same name (we even had the addres being the same at one time).

```
DELETE  c1
FROM    tblm_customer c1
        , tblm_customer c2
WHERE   c1.FirstName = c2.FirstName 
        AND c1.LastName = c2.LastName 
        AND c1.CustomerID < c2.CustomerID
```

Comment: it will generaERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'TBLM_CUSTOMER' for update in FROM clausete error like

Comment: @chetan, I've altered the statement. Previous statement worked with SQL Server. This should work using MySQL.