# How to delete duplicate records in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete duplicate rows from a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770228/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-mysql-table)

I've a mysql table with duplicate records and I want to delete all duplicate records. How can I do this? My table has only a few columns and 1 column can have duplicate records. It's a about a registration of user and I don't want an e-mail to be registerd twice. I cannot check the e-mail before it's entered because it would complicate the registration process and it has to be as simple as possible.

Comment: The title says "duplicate records", but the question has "duplicate columns". Can you give clear example?

Comment: You cannot have two columns with the same name; so do you have duplicate rows?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean duplicate records on 1 column.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The example you linked is about all the other columns identical, too. I need only 1 column to be dupelicate?

Comment: Can you update the question with a sample of your duplicated data and what you want to the result to be?

Comment: Check out http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_2201621_2/Deleting-Duplicate-Rows-in-a-MySQL-Database.htm

Comment: Records may be duplicate in 1 column, but have different values in other columns. You need some criteria to determine which records to delete.

Comment: If you have two records with the same email, how do you know which one to delete?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I store the timestamp. Maybe the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a self-join in the multiple-table form of [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE u1
FROM   users u1 JOIN users u2 USING (email)
WHERE  u1.timestamp < u2.timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks. What is using means? Does this work with 2 duplicated records only or with many?

Comment: @Chiyou: For each `email`, it will delete all matching records except the most recent.