# Delete duplicate ip address entry in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, ip-address

I have duplicate IP Address records in my database like this :

```
id | ipaddress
1    192.168.xxx.xxx
2    192.168.xxx.xxx
3    111.118.xxx.xxx
4    111.118.xxx.xxx
```

I want unique ip addresses in my field. How should I delete all duplicate entry?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen with the ids?

Comment: Is this a one-time fix or ongoing?

Comment: After you delete the duplicates, put a unique constraint on that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting duplicates in MySQL is a bit tricky because of the stupid restriction that the table cannot be referenced in a sub-select. Therefor the sub-select needs to be re-written into a join:

```
DELETE d
FROM mytable d
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT min(id) as min_id
   FROM   mytable
   GROUP BY trim(ipaddress)
) tokeep ON tokeep.min_id = d.id
WHERE keep.min_id IS NULL;
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cfb9c/1

**Edit**

There is actually a way to get around the stupid sub-select restriction. If the table is wrapped into a derived table inside the sub-select, the MySQL parser doesn't notice this and happily deletes with a sub-select:

```
delete mt 
from mytable mt
where exists (
    select * 
    from (
      select id, ipaddress
      from mytable
    ) ex
    where TRIM(ex.ipaddress) = TRIM(mt.ipaddress)
   and ex.id < mt.id
)
```

Comment: Now that's an ugly syntax construct to hide the selfjoin.

Comment: @wildplasser: The selfjoin is not "hidden". It's the sub-select that needs to be worked around. And I agree: it's ugly (and a *really* stupid restriction). See my edit for a *really* ugly workaround.

Comment: The braced version is a clever way to play hide-and-seek with the plan-generator. Does it force a "materialised" sub-select result table? NOTE: the grouping subselect appears to work as well.

Comment: @wildplasser: I have no idea. And I'm actually not sure if this is "supported". Maybe it will do something completely different in the background without telling - after all it's MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
        (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , ipaddress varchar
        );
INSERT INTO mytable(id, ipaddress) VALUES
 (1, '192.168.xxx.xxx')
,(2, '192.168.xxx.xxx ')        --<< note trailing whitespace
,(3, '111.118.xxx.xxx')
,(4, '111.118.xxx.xxx')
        ;
SELECT * FROM mytable;

DELETE FROM mytable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable ex
  WHERE ex.ipaddress = mt.ipaddress
  AND ex.id < mt.id
  )
  ;
SELECT * FROM mytable;

DELETE FROM mytable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable ex
  WHERE TRIM(ex.ipaddress) = TRIM(mt.ipaddress)
  AND ex.id < mt.id
  )
  ;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

OUTPUT:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 id |    ipaddress     
----+------------------
  1 | 192.168.xxx.xxx
  2 | 192.168.xxx.xxx 
  3 | 111.118.xxx.xxx
  4 | 111.118.xxx.xxx
(4 rows)

DELETE 1
 id |    ipaddress     
----+------------------
  1 | 192.168.xxx.xxx
  2 | 192.168.xxx.xxx 
  3 | 111.118.xxx.xxx
(3 rows)

DELETE 1
 id |    ipaddress    
----+-----------------
  1 | 192.168.xxx.xxx
  3 | 111.118.xxx.xxx
(2 rows)
```

UPDATE: added testdata and changed one record to have trailing whitspace.

NOTE: the names of the stringfunctions may vary between DMBS implementations. The TRIM() function works for postgres, maybe mysql has another name for the same thing.

UPDATE2: since mysql appears to not allow selfjoins in delete statements a workaround would be to use an auxillary  table with the ids of the records you (don't) want to keep.

(the solution by @ahose_with_no_name is shorter, but this one tries to keep close to the plain-vanilla SQL) :

```
CREATE table without_dups(id INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO without_dups(id)
SELECT id
FROM mytable mt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable ex
  WHERE ex.ipaddress = mt.ipaddress
  AND ex.id < mt.id
  )
  ;

DELETE FROM mytable mt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM without_dups nx
  WHERE nx.id = mt.id
  )
  ;

DROP TABLE without_dups;

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Maybe ipaddress is a varchar(xxx) field and some of the records have trailing whitespace ?

Comment: It showing the following error : `MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mt
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM mytable ex WHERE ex.ipaddress = mt.ipaddre' at line 1 `

Comment: MySQL does not allow the table you are deleting from to be used in a sub-select.

Comment: I'm sorry. In that case I am afraid I can't help the OP. OTOH: maybe tuck it into a view? Or a CTE ? ;-)

Comment: MySQL does not have CTEs, let alone writeable ones.

Comment: A bit nitpicking on terminology: MySQL's restriction isn't for a selfjoin. It's for a sub-select (including co-related ones). My solution does use a self-join (but not a sub-select)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE * FROM MyTable AS aa INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) as MID, id, ipaddress FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY id, ipaddress HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS bb ON bb.id = aa.id AND bb.ipaddress = aa.ipaddress
  AND bb.MID <> aa.id;
```

[Visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770228/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-mysql-table)