# Delete duplicate text in TextField mysql and can't make it unique

Tags: mysql

I can't delete the duplicate rows, because can't set the textfield to unique, how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide considerably more information as it's unclear as to what you're asking here.

Comment: the textField in mysql how can I delete a duplicate rows?, I've tried to set it to unique, but I can't, thats what I am asking, how to do it, because I have a big table, i need to quick delete those duplicates rows, even If i create a hash_text field, those duplicates in the textField will stay anyway, how to remove them

Comment: @Hello - is there any primary key for that table? for example some auto increment value....

Comment: @Hello - please provide you table structure

Answer (score 0):

Use query like this

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `forigen key` in the table, you must change values in other tables also..
Otherwise see this links:

[How to remove duplicate entries from a mysql db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867530/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-mysql-db)

[How to delete duplicate rows from a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770228/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-mysql-table)

[Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)