# Delete duplicate records and randomly keep one

Tags: mysql

How can I delete duplicate records and randomly retain one record in MYSQL?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 6):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to add a unique index, and specify the `IGNORE` option so it doesn't get errors:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (products_id, categories_id);
```

UPDATE:

To get the choice to be random, create a new table with the same schema as the old one, but with a unique key on these columns. Then do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO newtable
SELECT * from oldtable
ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

The first of each duplicate in the random ordering will be inserted into the new table, the rest will be ignored because of the IGNORE option.

Comment: This deletes any duplicate records already inserted in the table? +1 for it! It's great!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767837/delete-duplicate-record-from-same-table-in-mysql for another way, but it assumes there's another column that's guaranteed to be different among all the duplicates.

Comment: how does alter ignore retain a record?  I want it to randomly select one record

Comment: It retains the first record of each duplicate set. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: Are there anyways to randomly keep one record of the duplicates?

Comment: @user1761173 What's the point? if they're identical, what difference does it make if it's the first, the last, or any of them?

Comment: @Barranka Those two columns being identical doesn't mean the rows are identical.

Comment: @MichaelMior If it doesn't matter which row is kept, i think there's no point forcing a random choice ;-)

Comment: only one of the column is identical. I want the other value of the column to be randomly selected