# How to delete the duplicate record from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to delete duplicate records from table. The table does not have primary key (ID), so answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767876/125562) are not suitable.

Here is my try:

```
DELETE FROM afscp_permit
USING afscp_permit, afscp_permit AS vtable
WHERE (NOT afscp_permit.field_name=vtable.field_name)
AND (afscp_permit.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

Comment: Delete duplicates based on specific column or whole row?

Comment: And what's wrong... what happens?

Comment: duplicate value of single column called field_name, if it is alreday existed then delete that row

Comment: @d'alar'cop, nothing happens, condition is never true and is therefore meaningless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicates on mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table)

Comment: Better duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Following might help if there is no bug in your DBMS and no constraints are in the way:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE afscp_permit ADD UNIQUE INDEX field_name_index (field_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a temporary table with the same columns and doing:

```
INSERT INTO temp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM afscp_permit;
DELETE FROM afscp_permit;
INSERT INTO afscp_permit SELECT * FROM temp;
DROP TABLE temp;
```